# Include file in the maven target jar

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a file `pythonScript.py` in the resource directory of my application. After building the jar the file is located in `target\MyApp\BOOT-INF\classes`

Now when I call this file directly `pythonScript.py`, I am getting the following error:

`file -  python.py does not exists`

This is how I'm calling the python file:

**Java code**

```
private static final String imageRemoverScript = "removeImages.py";

String[] cmd = { "python", imageRemoverScript, File.getAbsolutePath(),
                 basePath.concat(fileName.concat(new String("" + fileCount))) };

ScriptCallerUtility.pythonScript(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have included the python file into the jar file, if the Python file is in the resources folder and you have a maven project.

So what you can actually do is to create a Java executable class which extracts the Python file from the classpath and copies the the Python file to a temporary file. Then you execute the temporary file and after that you delete it.

Here is an example which implements the actions described above:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PythonRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path temp = Files.createTempFile("py", ".py"); // Create temporary file with prefix, suffix
        try (InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.py")) {
            Files.copy(in, temp, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); // Copy to temporary file.
            // Execute the file and do whatever your need
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
                    "C:\\Users\\BLAH\\python.exe", temp.toString()).start();
            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream())) {
                scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
                System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }
            Files.deleteIfExists(temp); // Delete the temporary file.
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply run this using a command similar to this one using the produced jar file:

```
java -cp project.example-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.fernandes.python.run.PythonRunner
```

If `sample.py` contains:

```
print ("hi")
```

You will see this console:

```
hi
```